# How to configure optimistic locking in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq, optimistic-locking

From [jOOQ Manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual-single-page/#codegen-advanced) it is not clear at least to me how to properly configure optimistic locking.

```
 <!-- All table and view columns that are used as "version" fields for
   optimistic locking (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions).
   See UpdatableRecord.store() and UpdatableRecord.delete() for details -->

<recordVersionFields>REC_VERSION</recordVersionFields>
```

and below

```
recordVersionFields: Relevant methods from super classes are overridden to return the VERSION field
```

What does it actually mean? Could someone provide an example?

Imagine if have this table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
   "id"      INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('global_seq') NOT NULL,
   "code"    TEXT                                  NOT NULL,
   "version" INTEGER                               NOT NULL
);
```

What should I put into `recordVersionFields` into pom.xml?

```
<database>
    <inputSchema>PUBLIC</inputSchema>
    <recordVersionFields>users.version</recordVersionFields>
</database>
```

`users.version`, `version`, `RECORD_VERSION`?

I use H2 database, if I set just `version` then compilation error appears.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/JooqDemo/target/generated-sources/jooq-h2/org/jooqdemo/generated/tables/SchemaVersion.java:[152,52] getRecordVersion() in org.jooqdemo.generated.tables.SchemaVersion cannot implement getRecordVersion() in org.jooq.Table
  return type org.jooq.TableField<org.jooqdemo.generated.tables.records.SchemaVersionRecord,java.lang.String> is not compatible with org.jooq.TableField<org.jooqdemo.generated.tables.records.SchemaVersionRecord,? extends java.lang.Number>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these regular expression patterns that you can supply to the code generator are patterns that match schemas, tables, or columns either by their *unqualified* name (e.g. `version`) or by their *fully qualified* name (e.g. `public.users.version`). You cannot use partially qualified names like `users.version`.

To answer your concrete question, the following are examples that will work:

```
<!-- Will match version columns in all tables -->
<recordVersionFields>version</recordVersionFields>

<!-- Will match version columns in all user tables. 
     Notice that schema names are matched by .* -->
<recordVersionFields>.*\.user\.version</recordVersionFields>

<!-- Will match version columns only in that particular public.user table -->
<recordVersionFields>public\.user\.version</recordVersionFields>
```

This will generate the relevant meta information into your `UserRecord` for optimistic locking to be enabled on `UserRecord.store()`, `update()`, and `delete()` calls.

#### Side note: Your compilation error

In your question, you referred to a compilation error that seems to happen because you're matching all version columns in all tables:

```
<!-- Will match version columns in all tables -->
<recordVersionFields>version</recordVersionFields>
```

This will also match "wrong" version columns, e.g. in the `schema_version` table, which is of type `VARCHAR` not `INTEGER`. Perhaps, you should be more explicit with your regular expression to do exact matching.

#### Side note: Case sensitivity

All of these regular expressions are case sensitive. If you're using PostgreSQL, then the following is probably wrong:

```
<inputSchema>PUBLIC</inputSchema>
```

Instead, write any of these:

```
<!-- use lower-case in PostgreSQL by default -->
<inputSchema>public</inputSchema>

<!-- use case-insensitive regular expressions to "stay safe" --> 
<inputSchema>(?i:PUBLIC)</inputSchema>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. However I get compilation error from generator. I have added to the original post.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: That compilation error happens because some of your `version` columns are not of type `INTEGER` but `VARCHAR`. You perhaps shouldn't match all `version` columns. I'll add that to the answer

Comment: yes, thank you, I have not realized that Flyway generates that schema_version table in H2,

Comment: @LukasEder what is the difference in the pojo generated code? I don't see any difference or my generator is not configured correctly.. thanks.

Comment: @Gadi: I'm not sure, I don't know what you've configured. Would you mind asking a new question, perhaps? EDIT: I've seen you've just created this issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5706. I'll answer there